# Spring Maven repository issue

Tags: spring, maven, repository

A sample Spring project contains the following POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.prospinghibernate.gallery</groupId>
    <artifactId>gallery</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gallery</name>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>3.5.0-Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss Repo</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2</url>
            <name>JBoss Repo</name>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>ibiblio mirror</id>
            <url>http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- General dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <!-- Exclusions only required for version 1.2.15 of log4j -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.9.M2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- file upload dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- image processing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!--Spring OXM-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- H2 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.131</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ehcache dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm-attrs</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!--Hibernate Search-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Dozer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1-beta-1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.22</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I get the following error message when I try to run the Spring sample application:

> Failed to execute goal on project gallery: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project
>   com.prospinghibernate.gallery:gallery:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to
>   collect dependencies for [log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15 (compile),
>   org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.0 (compile),
>   org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.0 (compile),
>   org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.0 (compile),
>   org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.9.M2 (compile),
>   javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5 (provided),
>   commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1 (compile),
>   javax.media:jai-core:jar:1.1.3 (compile),
>   org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (compile),
>   org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (test),
>   org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (compile),
>   org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE
>   (compile), org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (compile),
>   org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (compile),
>   org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (compile),
>   org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (compile),
>   org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (compile),
>   org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (compile),
>   jstl:jstl:jar:1.2 (compile), com.h2database:h2:jar:1.2.131 (compile),
>   net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.6.2 (compile),
>   org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.5.0-Final (compile),
>   org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.5.0-Final (compile),
>   org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final
>   (compile), org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.0.2.GA (compile),
>   javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA (compile),
>   cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2 (compile), javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1
>   (compile), org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE
>   (compile), org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE (compile),
>   commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4 (compile),
>   commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.3 (compile),
>   org.hibernate:hibernate-search:jar:3.2.1.Final (compile),
>   net.sf.dozer:dozer:jar:5.2.2 (compile),
>   org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.4.0 (compile),
>   junit:junit:jar:4.8.1 (test), org.jmock:jmock-junit4:jar:2.5.1
>   (test)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.9.M2: Could not transfer artifact
>   org.aspectj:aspectjrt:pom:1.6.9.M2 from/to JBoss Repo
>   (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2): Access denied to:
>   http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.6.9.M2/aspectjrt-1.6.9.M2.pom
>   -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2) repository has been moved to https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public

Try to remove this entry from your `pom.xml`

```
<repository>
  <id>JBoss Repo</id>
   <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2</url>
   <name>JBoss Repo</name>
</repository>
```

Comment: If I remove that entry I get: Failed to execute goal on project gallery: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.prospinghibernate.gallery:gallery:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.9.M2 in http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of ibiblio mirror has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Comment: There is no `org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.9.M2` in ibiblio nor in JBoss repository. If you don't need this exact version of aspectjrt then try changing it to `1.6.12` (the latest for this moment)

Answer (score 1):

Your org.aspectj:aspectrt:1.6.9.M2 cannot be found in the maven central reporsitory.
Solution to fix your maven build:

1) You can change your version to 1.6.12 and add following repository

```
<repository>
    <id>JBoss Repository</id>
    <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2</url>
    <name>JBoss Repository</name>
</repository>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.12</version>
</dependency>
```

2) You can change your version to 1.5.3 and add following repository

```
<repository>
    <id>ibiblio mirror</id>
    <url>http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/</url>
    <name>ibiblio repo</name>
</repository>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```